# Create DynamoDB tables locally from SAM Template yaml file

Tags: amazon-dynamodb-local

How can I create tables a Dynamo DB locally using the same `template.yaml` file with `AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31` definition for SAM/Cloud Formation that  I intent to use for production?

DynamoDB is running locally using `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local` but has no tables.

Answer (score 1):

By installing a CLI parser for yaml, example [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) that reassembles the popular `jq`, you can run a linux command like this to configure your local Dynamo DB tables. This expects your DynamoDB to run on the standard port 8000 for local development:

```bash
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-yaml "`cat template.yaml | yq .Resources.[MY TABLE NAME].Properties`" --no-cli-pager --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Verify the creation using

```bash
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```